# Limit the number of decimal and length of number with regex in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have been trying to validate a number that limits the decimal point to 3 points and the length of the number (including the dot) to 6, but couldn't get it to validate properly. This is so far what I have:

```
^([0-9]([.][0-9]{1,3})?){1,6}$
```

How could I change the regex above to validate properly? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex for checking length:

```
^(?=[0-9.]{1,6}$)[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJ6fI0/1)

Answer (score 2):

For the total length I would just check the string length:

```
if(s.Length <= 6 && Regex.IsMatch(s, @"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,3})?$")) {

}
```

Because the `{1,6}` at the end of your expression means 0 to 6 repetitions of the term preceeding it (in your case, the whole number). It does not limit the length of the string.